# $\lim_{x\to 2} \, \sqrt{x-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \, \sqrt{x-2}$$

When you take the right hand limit for this expression, you get $0$. However, if you take the left hand side it gives an imaginary number.

However, do you consider the imaginary part when taking the limit (in which case both sides would tend to $0$) or do you consider the limit to be undefined because it cannot be approached from the left in the field of real numbers.

Comment: Since this is likely a question from an introductory calculus or analysis course, you've restricted yourself to the real numbers. In this case, you can only approach from the right since, as you note, the limit from the left gives an imaginary number. This is a general rule of thumb in such situations. Even in a complex analysis course, square roots (as functions) are a little technical to deal with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is tricky.  Part of the issue is what does the symbol $\sqrt{\cdot}$ mean?  If $a$ is a positive real number, we denote by $\sqrt{a}$ the positive real number whose square is $a$.  Usually, if we want a square root of a negative or complex number, we have to be very specific about which square root.  For example, we usually say $i$ is *the* square root of $-1$, but this isn't quite right, since $-i$ is also a square root of $-1$.

In calculus, when dealing with functions of real variables, we don't want to get into this sticky territory, so we say that the domain of the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is the set of non-negative reals.  Therefore, if we want to take a limit as $x$ goes to $0$, we can only consider paths to $0$ that lie within the domain of the function.  In this case, that means we can only take a 'right hand' limit.

Interestingly, though, we could think of $f$ as a complex valued function, so taking a 'left hand' limit would give
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\to 2^{-}} \sqrt{x-2} &=& \lim_{x\to 2^{-}} \\ &=&\lim_{x\to 2^-} \sqrt{(-1)(2-x)}\\ 
&=&   \lim_{x\to 2^{-}} i\;\sqrt{2-x}\\
&=& i \cdot  \lim_{x\to 2^{-}} \sqrt{2-x}\\
&=& 0,
\end{eqnarray*}
so, in a certain sense, everything checks out.

Comment: So basically if you set sqrt(x) as only producing real values then  limit does not exist, but if you allow complex values then it is 0?

Comment: Not quite.  The limit exists and is equal to $0$ in the real case (as you state in your question).  I was pointing out that even if you do allow for a left hand limit, then you have to work with complex numbers, but the limit is still equal to $0$.

Comment: I don't quite understand -- in the real case you can't approach it from the left, so wouldn't the limit be undefined?

Comment: In the real case note that the definition of limit of a function at a given point $x_0$ requires that there is an open interval containing $x_0$ such that the function is defined everywhere in $(a,b)$ except possibly at $x_0$. In your case there is no open interval containing $2$ where the function is defined. So the concept of limit existing is itself moot.

Comment: @Shahab You are sort of correct, but this is subtle, since 'open' often means 'open in the subspace topology'.  When you say an open interval, what you actually mean is an open subset of the domain of the function.  Since [2, $\infty)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it inherits a topology from $\mathbb{R}$.  Precisely, the open subsets of $[2, \infty)$ are defined to  be the open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ intersected with $[2, \infty)$.  Therefore $[2, 2 + \epsilon)$ is an open subset of $[2, \infty)$ for any positive $\epsilon$.  The concept of limit existing is not moot.